# Upgrade to androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0 issues

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I just updated our Android project to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

from

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

And suddenly, the app is very slow.

Information about the project:

- MVVM architecture
- Using [dev.b3nedikt.restring:restring:4.0.3](https://github.com/B3nedikt/restring)

In the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.2.0) it says that:

Deprecated AppCompatDelegate.attachBaseContext(). If you are calling or overriding this method, use AppCompatDelegate.attachBaseContext2() instead.

In all activities, I call:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
super.attachBaseContext(ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap(Restring.wrapContext(newBase ?: this)))
```

}

However, removing it does not seems to solve the problem.

Does anyone have similar issues?

Comment: did you find any solution?